# Is it good to tell awakening stories?

Tags: meditation-practicalities, tibetan-buddhism, spiritual-materialism

My question to all my dear friend is why people use to share there stories of awakening ?
will it affect the mind of others those who are meditating to find the inner peace.

Comment: Yes!...........

Answer (score 1):

I think at times it can be helpful, and at times, harmful.

The teachings of the Buddha are his experiences. By sharing his atainments, he helps us all walk the path.

Unfortunately, if you are too descriptive, people will seek your experience in their practice. They may come to false conclusions that make guiding themselves toards the next attainment much more difficult.

I think it may be more helpful to others if someone with attainments focuses on another's practice, and asks them to answer questions that spark introspection that leads them toward their next fruition.

Answer (score 1):

> The hand in the rock is not for the master.It is for the student.

When Milarepa’s disciple saw his master do something that tradition and other teachers said could not happen, **it helped him break through his beliefs about what is possible.** He saw his teacher’s mastery with his own eyes. `And because he witnessed the miracle personally, his experience told his mind that he wasn’t limited or bound by the “laws” of reality as they were known at the time.`

Marpa occultly manifested himself in the forms of Gaypa Dorje and other of the tutelary divinities of the Kargyutpa sect and also other divine shapes and forms along with the various symbols associated with each deity such as bells, gems, lotuses, swords, etc. He then explained that these were various *psycho-physical powers* obtained after enlightenment and that they should never be manifested for an unworthy cause. This was his parting gift to Milarepa, and this, his spiritual son, greatly exalted in his heart to see that his Guru Marpa was veritably a Buddha himself.

He vowed that he himself would gain such powers and show them in his turn to his own disciples. `Marpa then told him that he could now depart since he had demonstrated the mirage like nature of all existing things.` He instructed Milarepa to meditate in various caves made holy by previous saints in the locale of Mount Kailas, Lapchi Kang (Mt. Everest), and other sanctified places. He then gave to Milarepa a sealed scroll that was to be opened only on dire threat of imminent death. With great sadness, knowing they would not meet again in the present life, Milarepa took leave of his beloved Spiritual Father and Mother with the thought that they would all meet again in the celestial realms.                         `Source:Milarepa of Tibet`